# DHCP on USB0 of Pi Zero not working

Tags: pi-zero, dhcp, gadget

I have set up my Raspberry Pi Zero with the USB Ethernet gadget as described by [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget).

This works wonderfully with static IP addresses. Now I want to put a little DHCP server in the Pi, so that I don't have to configure a static IP every time I connect to it.

Since I have no network connection, I've downloaded and manually installed using `dpkg` the `isc-dhcp-server_4.3.1-6+deb8u2_armhf.deb` and `lsb-base_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb` packages.

Next, I set up`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.7.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.169.7.10 192.168.7.20;
option routers 192.168.7.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.7.255;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local";
}
```

and /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
DHCPD_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
DHCPD_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
INTERFACES="usb0"
```

And `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    broadcast 192.168.7.255
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

When I now try:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status isc-dhcp-server
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-03-18 08:23:07 UTC; 16s ago
  Process: 454 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xn
No journal files were found.
```

I don't have a clue what's wrong, and the lack of error messages is not helping. It seems like the DHCP server does not even start.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 2):

I tired to copy your config to see if I could get it working ... I noted

```
`range 192.169.7.10 192.168.7.20;`
```

192.169 in the range is invalid for that subnet... should be:

```
`range 192.168.7.10 192.168.7.20;`
```